# How to get form data onSubmission in React-remix by using useFetcher Hook using fetcher.submit()

Tags: remix

I have a simple component with an input field and a submit button. I just want to get my data after i fill the input field and submit the form. by using useFetcher hook and fetcher.submit().

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useFetcher } from '@remix-run/react'
import { ActionFunction } from '@remix-run/node';

function fetchHook() {

    const fetch = useFetcher();

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect");
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1> Use Fetcher Hook</h1>
            <fetch.Form action='/fetcher' method='post'>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="" />
                    <button type='submit' > Submit</button>
                </div>
            </fetch.Form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default fetchHook;

export const action: ActionFunction = async ({ request }) => {


}
```

> What changes should i make to get my desired result. I am new to react-remix.

Comment: can't you use normal form submission using inbuild `Form` element in remix?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
  const fetcher = useFetcher();

  if (fetcher.formData) {
    for (const data of fetcher.formData.entries()) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  }
```

to access submitted data, but `fetcher.formData` seems to switch between undefined and a value